# Notify me only of actual incidents when subscribed to Stack Overflow status page (stackstatus.net)

Tags: feature-request, email-notification, subscription, stackstatus

I noticed this in my inbox today:

[image: email notification of non important status update]

When I subscribed to the status page, I expected to get emails only for actual incidents, that also appear in the [history page](https://www.stackstatus.net/history) (e.g. [this one](https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/26901c23-eddf-48de-acbb-ba8cf2ab2454)), but alas, looks like it means I'm getting email for any small change done internally. That's not what I'm after, so I unsubscribed for now.

Can this please be changed so that ordinary people subscribing to the status page will get notified only for important incidents that affect the network? Think it's called "p2 and above" in the technical jargon.